# How to make a different font and color of text in labels?

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible to make a bold or italic, and change the color of individual words Label? 
Example: the first line is bold in red text, font 12, second row 10 green italic font

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not possible yet. For a related recent discussion check http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/HTML-tags-in-label-expresion-on-QGIS-2-0-1-td5084946.html.

Comment: There is also an [existing feature request](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/4080). Please add to it, if needed.

Comment: @underdark, any update on this in the newer versions of QGIS?  The link in your answer is not working anymore.

Comment: @artwork21 according to the feature request status the work is in progress