# Adjusting text style in multiline label in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, fields-attributes, multi-values

In QGIS 3.16 I have a 3 lined label

```
"Projekt" || '\n' || "Art" || '\n' || "Bearb"
```

How can I make only the text of the first line (`"Projekt"`) bold or a bigger size?

Comment: You can't. But you can use rule based labeling to create two different labels, forcing them to be above each other using the placement rules.

Comment: This tutorial from Klas Karlsson (youtube video) may give you some idea on how to get there : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySYmZv7HQiY&ab_channel=KlasKarlsson

Comment: You might look at this workaround: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380964/qgis-labels-with-html-formating

Comment: For the rule based labeling, see this [one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195848/assigning-different-colors-to-different-parts-of-text-in-labels-using-qgis?rq=1) .. though Johns' linked solution using SVG is much more robust

Answer (score 6):

In QGIS 3.16, in label properties, you can check 'render as HTML', so that Labels can be interpreted as HTML code. Than your label can be writed as:

```
'<b>'||"Projekt"||'</b>' || '<br>' || "Art" || '<br>' || "Bearb"
```

you use `<b></b>` to write bold style and `<br>` to change line.
In my solution I have supposed that Projekt,Art and Bearb are attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

HTML Styling in labels is currently limited to colors, but you can work around that by using John's dynamic SVG solutions (see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381241/180975) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/379578/180975)), or by exporting to SVG (keep text as text objects) and edit the labels manually in Inkscape or Illustrator. Also, this feature may be coming soon, as [katagena](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/145164/katagena) helpfully pointed out [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/441110/180975).

Edit: katagena's answer has been removed. See [Babel](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/88814/babel)'s [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/441124/180975) instead.

Answer (score 1):

In 3.16 this is not possible with a single label but in the following QGIS 3.28 (will be released October 2022) this will be implemented. See more at [blog post by North Road](https://north-road.com/2022/09/09/mixed-format-labels-in-qgis-coming-soon/) .

You might use a workaround in 3.16 by using Rule-based labeling and adding each line as own label and defining the vertical offset for each:
[image: screenshot of rule based labels]
[image: screenshot of setting the offset]